# Store and retrieve multiple documents in free vector stores based on critria

Tags: python, nlp, reference-request, vector-database

I am new to vector stores, and so far experimented with storing 1 file in Faiss and Pinecone. I am looking for tutorials that teach me how to save multiple files in free versions of any vector store, and retrieve them based on a user criteria. For instance, I could have document on sports and other on health, and through choice of user for specific words, I need to be able to retrieve the correct document and run search on them.